# How to change status when clicking on a specific node

Tags: javascript, onclick, nodelist

I'm trying to create a gallery. Most of it already works thanks to some online tutorials. 
On the final page there should be a slider and also some thumbnails to click on which will effect the slider. I tried to achieve this by working with status. The problem I'm facing right now is to change the status when clicking on the matching img.

```
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgs img');
let status = 0;
var num = document.querySelectorAll('.profile_pics img').length;
let maxstatus = status + num;

imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener('click', imgClick));

function imgClick(){
  for(let f = 0; f < imgs.length; f++){ 
    if(imgs[f].click == true){
      status = [f];
    }
  }
}

// Rest of the code (is working)

function reset(){
  for(let i = 0; i < maxstatus; i++){
    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
    slides[i].classList.add('fade_in');
    imgs[i].style.opacity = 1;
  }
}

function focus(){
  imgs[status].style.opacity = opacity;
  }

function startSlide(){
  reset();
  slides[0].style.display = 'block';
}


function slideLeft(){
  reset();
  slides[status - 1].style.display = 'block';
  status--;
  focus()
  console.log(status);
}


function slideRight(){
  reset();
  slides[status + 1].style.display = 'block';
  status++;
  focus()
  console.log(status);
}


prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(status === 0){
    status = maxstatus;
  }
  slideLeft();
});


nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(status === maxstatus - 1){
    status = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

I've tried now for a couple of hours but can't find a solution. Worked with console.log of course but simply can't get the status update working when clicking of one of those images.

Help would be appreciated - Thanks a lot

Comment: its best to include some more code so that we can test our solutions before submitting it to you. you may use pastbin.com or jsfiddle, etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Full Code Can Be Found Here: [Paste Bin Link](https://pastebin.com/7zPEWEJN)

**Update:**

```
// Global Variable
let status = -1;
let imgs = [
    $('#img0'),
    $('#img1'),
    $('#img2'),
    $('#img3'),
    $('#img4'),
    $('#img5'),
]

// Functions
function imgClick(elm){
    status = imgs.indexOf(elm); // This will set the status variable to the element index, using indexOf function. it will check inside of imgs variable which element index it is, if it cant be found status will return a -1  value
}

// Execute
imgs.forEach(img => img.on('click', () => {
    imgClick(img);  
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help so far and sorry for replying so late..

Tried both of your scripts - maybe its a dumb question but: is "elm" a placeholder? If not then unfortunately it doens't work..

Comment: 2nd. script error: 0: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @Alex `elm` is the img variable, from the `imgs.forEach` you need to pass in the element from the array, also imgs variable must be global... lets go to chat...

Comment: lets start a chat

Comment: have a look at this: [example.html](https://pastebin.com/7zPEWEJN) also i've used [jQuery Library](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: as you may have noticed, i'm fairly new here and don't quite know where to find a chat :D

thanks for the code so far I tried it and it works almost exactly as I wnat it to work. 

the main problem I do encounter with this code is, that I don't know how many pictures there will be on the final page. 

I could give you a range but no final number. so as soon as I add some pictures to your code, they won't count towards the counter status

Comment: the chat option usually appear of some back to back comments

Comment: user11407055 has only 6 reputation, not yet enough to chat